Adjust element dimensions, including text size, according to available space
I have a very minimalistic interface that contains two areas: a submit button area and a content area. The entire interface should always be completely visible onscreen with the user never having to scroll to see everything. While the submit button should always occupy at least a certain amount of screenspace, the content area can have anywhere between 1 and several (lets say 8) elements.
These elements should share the rest of the available vertical screen space and scale according to it, including the text displayed inside them. Making elements grow and shrink with css-flex is usually available, using it does not adjust the font-size to allow the text to grow accordingly for readability.
Is this possible in pure css or do I need to calculate the available space of an element and use js to make adjustments to the elements on the fly depending on the amount of items and the available space?
A fiddle with an example for the layout: https://jsfiddle.net/xpyLz0rv/
This needs to look the same on all devices, and on all devices it needs to fit onscreen and be legible. Yes the content of the buttons are only letters and the only lengthy text is the submit button's label.
Example:


.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content-area {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.content-area > * {
   /* ??? */
}

.submit-area {
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 20%;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-area">
        <button>A</button>
        <button>B</button>
        <button>C</button>
    </div>
    <div class="submit-area">
        <button>Send Choice</button>
    </div>
</div>




Your question is quite unclear. Please limit the text to the actual issue.

Can you please clarify what is unclear?

If you are looking to scale the font to fit a space, I'd suggest that you might want to create an SVG which you could insert and scale instead of doing the text in HTML.

How the end result would look like in your example is not clear. You mention in the question that it must handle a lot of content, but your example only have a single letter in 3 buttons.

Your .container should be equal to the height of the screen, so something like 100vh. You can probably figure the rest of it out :)

Added a fiddle for Rodrigo.

I won't post it as an answer because it doesn't address the whole topic effectively.. but I have a bunch of suggestions: 1. style the body as {padding:0; margin: 0;} 2. use height: 100vh;box-sizing: border-box; in your .container since using 100% requires a further parent container having its own size (that you don't have here); 3. your submit area might be positioned sticky to the bottom but that's not required.. it's ok also as that as a special flex item of the set;

use vh as your unit for font-size.. something like 10vh to begin with.. and you'll see the actual font size scaling according to the available height. In general if you have sizes to set try to remain relative to the vh and see if it's feasible. If you need further scaling logics you may need javascript. Plus in general add borders to your element so you'll see their actual box model size rendered beyond their content

What you are looking for is something similar to the text AGENTIC on link. Like @ControlAltDel said, create an SVG then insert it because 10vw or 10vh will not always always scale and fit the available sapce. Using an SVG will give you that flexibility.

This might help (btw remember that because you are working in JSFiddle the VH will not be 100% of the actual view height of you browser and it will cause you to scroll while in JSFiddle but outside of that it will work) Tell me if this helps!
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Default font for better readability */
}

.container {
    height: 100vh; /* Full viewport height */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between; /* Space between content area and submit area */
    align-items: center;
}

.content-area {
    flex-grow: 1; /* Allow this area to grow and fill available space */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly; /* Space buttons evenly */
    align-items: center; /* Center buttons */
}

.content-area button {
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 4rem; /* Fixed width for buttons */
    height: 4rem; /* Fixed height for buttons */
    font-size: calc(1rem + 1vw); /* Responsive font size */
    transition: font-size 0.2s; /* Smooth transition for font size */
}

.content-area input {
    padding: 0.8em; /* Padding for input field */
    font-size: calc(1rem + 1vw); /* Responsive font size */
    width: 80%; /* Make the input field take up most of the width */
    max-width: 300px; /* Limit the maximum width */
}

.submit-area {
    flex-grow: 0; /* Fixed height for submit area */
    display: flex;
    height: 10vh; /* Set to 10vh to reduce overall height */
    justify-content: center; /* Center the submit button */
    align-items: center; /* Center the submit button vertically */
}

.submit-area button {
    padding: 1em; /* Padding for submit button */
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: calc(1rem + 1vw); /* Responsive font size for submit button */
    transition: font-size 0.2s; /* Smooth transition for font size */
}

